# Does removing an application from Software Center do a remove or a purge

Tags: 11.10, software-center

When I remove an application already installed through the Software Center. Does it remove the app the same way as doing a purge to it (aptitude purge) or does it remove it like a "remove" (aptitude remove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it only does a remove, not a purge.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thanks for your answer. I feel that your answer could be a bit more detailed.