# How to use Ubuntu-provided virtualbox package after uninstalling virtualbox-4.1?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I installed Oracle Virtualbox per the instructions on the Oracle website, but can't use XP or Ubuntu VMs after switching back to the Ubuntu standard version.

To switch back, I have edited /etc/apt/sources.list to remove the Oracle repository, did an `apt-get update`, removed everything with virtualbox in the name using Ubuntu Software Center, and then reinstalled `virtualbox` and (after an error message) `virtualbox-dkms` packages.

I still can't start my virtual machines. How can I use the ubuntu version of Virtualbox again? The Oracle version crashes on my machine.  What are the 'extension packs' that the Virtualbox error message complains about? These are different from the 'guest additions', right?

Also, why does re-installing ubuntu Virtualbox in Software Center fail to produce a working virtualization environment?

here is the error message when starting XP in the Ubuntu version of virtualbox (Version4.1.2_Ubuntu r38459) :

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine XP, defaults.
The device helper structure version has changed.
If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox.     (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).
virtualbox_prob.txt (END)
```

and the error for an Ubuntu virtual machine:

```
 Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubu32.
The device helper structure version has changed.
If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of VirtualBox and the version of the extension packs that VirtualBox has installed must be the same or lower version. It looks like you still have 4.1.8 extensions packs installed in VirtualBox 4.1.2.

Open Virtualbox, on the File menu select preferences. A new window will open. Select Extensions. Now mark all extensions and uninstall them using the button with the small red x.

[image]

If you want to install again the extension pack (if you need to use USB or RDP), please go to this [page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_1), and download ones that match your VirtualBox version.

Comment: Does this mean that extension packs are not removed with purging Virtual Box to reinstall the OSE edition from the repositories?

Comment: I don't know. It sounds pausible, but I haven't checked it. I just had some experience with that error ;).

Comment: @JavierRivera Thanks, that fixed the problem! According to [Does removing an application from Software Center do a remove or a purge](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103146/does-removing-an-application-from-software-center-do-a-remove-or-a-purge) default on software center just does a remove. Maybe a purge would avoid the problem that I had.

Comment: alternatively from the command line you can use sudo VBoxManage list extpacks and sudo VBoxManage extpack uninstall VBoxVRDP

Comment: What time could have been saved by proper documentation ... Thanks, Javier.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem:
Installed VirtualBox using "Ubuntu Software Center"---> version= 4.2.10
Downloaded Extension Pack from virtualbox.org---> version= 4.2.18
After adding extension pack to VB and activating USB2.0 on a machine, the machine could not start. The error was as follows:

```
    Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Linux.

    The device helper structure version has changed.

    If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).

    Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
    Component: Console
    Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

THE SOLUTION I FOUND:
1) removing VB version 4.2.10 
2) downloading appropriate *.deb package of version 4.2.18 from virtualbox.org
3) installing that *.deb file using dpkg command
4) adding same version extension pack to new VB (4.1.18)
Now my USB2.0 works properly with my guest machine!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just execute

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-ext-pack
```